# How to get useParams hook as string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typeerror

I have a search page that is linked to the product detail page using the `productId`.

In the product detail page, I'm able to use:

```
const productId = useParams();
```

Then I have to cross it with a product list, to get the correct Product. For that, I use:

```
const productSelected = listOfProducts.find(e => e.productId === productId);
```

The problem is that the `productId` that I get from `useParams()`, comes as an object. And even though this objects holds the correct `productId`, it fails when I'm searching in the list, as `e.productId` is a string.

And I'm not able to use double `==`, as the JSLint won't allow me.
I saw some posts saying to use `JSON.Stringfy`, but it converts the whole object in string, and not only the value for `productId`.

Comment: I'm confused, is `productId` a string or an object? When `console.log(productId)` what do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this objects holds the correct productId

It sounds like you just need to destructure it?:

```
const { productId } = useParams();
```

This would declare the `productId` variable to have the value from the `productId` property on the object, not the whole object itself.

---

It's also worth noting that, by default, URL parameters are strings.  If you expect it to be a number then you can convert it as such.  Perhaps something like this:

```
const { productIdParam } = useParams();
const productId = parseInt(productIdParam);
```

---

Or, if you're using TypeScript, you can indicate the type when calling `useParams`.  For example:

```
const { productId } = useParams<{ productId: Number }>();
```

In this case `productId` will be a `Number`.

---

Based on comments below, it's also important to note something about types when using TypeScript.  It only enforces them at *design-time*, not a *run-time*.  So for example you can declare an interface to have a property that is a `Number`, and then use that interface when fetching data from somewhere.  But at runtime if the actual property value is a `string` then `===` won't work, because the types are wrong.  Even though TypeScript said they should be correct, at runtime it's all still JavaScript which doesn't enforce that.

Comment: I suspect this is the case, but also I suspect that the param is a string, but is a number in the items in `listOfProducts`.

Comment: Hey David and Alex, thanks for the support. I edited my question to make it easier to understand. The params is an object. But the item in the list is a string.
I tried what you suggested David, but doing it throws me the error: Property 'productId' does not exist on type {}

Comment: @Gustavopeq: Does the approach suggested here not work in some way?

Comment: @David I got it working, just had to make it const { productId } = useParams<{ productId: string }>()
What is weird that it still didn't work... And I'm printing the productId type, and it's string. The e.ProductId is declared as string as well, but when I print it's type, it shows number. But if the params to number, the find function doesn't accept it as it knows that e.productId is string. That's just so weird

Comment: @Gustavopeq: Keep in mind that TypeScript doesn't guarantee *runtime* type safety.  Only *design-time*.  If you're getting the data from somewhere and that data is a number, then it's a number.  Regardless of what TypeScript enforced at design-time, when you get to runtime it's all JavaScript which isn't statically typed.

Comment: @Gustavopeq: I like the type info you passed to the `useParams` though, that's cleaner than my `parseInt`.  I didn't know about that.  I'll update the answer to reflect it to help future readers.

Comment: Great... I'll find my way around the type issue. Thanks @David!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to destruct the object !
const productId  = useParams(); //return an object and inside this object there is a property called id contains the exact value of userParams() so you need just to access to this property "productId.id" .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).